# using exception in java

Tags: java, exception

i want to add to my code an exception in the bottom part

```
if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i1,j2)==false&&i1!=i2&&j1!=j2){
        return 0;
```

what i want to do is: if the "if" above is true, instead of doing "return 0" i will throw an exception that will check the code from this point

```
if (locationNeighbor(map,i1+1,j1,i1,j1)==2&&map2[i1+1][j1]==-1){ //down
            map2[i1+1][j1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1+1,j1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1+1,i1,j1)==3&&map2[i1][j1+1]==-1){
```

and then again if the "if" happens i will check the code from this area

```
 if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1+1,i1,j1)==3&&map2[i1][j1+1]==-1){ //right
        map2[i1][j1+1]=counter;
        return distance(map,i1,j1+1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
    }
```

and then last time i check

```
if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1-1,i1,j1)==4&&map2[i1][j1-1]==-1){ //left
        map2[i1][j1-1]=counter;
        return distance(map,i1,j1-1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
    }
```

this is my code

```
public static int distance(int[][] map, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2, int[][]map2, int counter) {
    if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i2,j2)==true){ // if its 1 step before the end
        map2[i2][j2]=counter; // put the last number
    }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1-1,j1,i1,j1)==1&&map2[i1-1][j1]==-1){ //up
            map2[i1-1][j1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1-1,j1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1+1,j1,i1,j1)==2&&map2[i1+1][j1]==-1){ //down
            map2[i1+1][j1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1+1,j1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1+1,i1,j1)==3&&map2[i1][j1+1]==-1){ //right
            map2[i1][j1+1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1,j1+1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        if (locationNeighbor(map,i1,j1-1,i1,j1)==4&&map2[i1][j1-1]==-1){ //left
            map2[i1][j1-1]=counter;
            return distance(map,i1,j1-1,i2,j2,map2,counter+1);
        }
        print(map2);
        if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i1,j2)==false&&i1!=i2&&j1!=j2){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int x=map2[i2][j2];
            return x;
        }
}
```

is this even possible with exception?

Comment: `throw new Exception()` ?  Or even define your own custom exception class.

Comment: So you want an exception thrown in place of the "return 0" in your final block of code? Or in place of every return?

Comment: i have never used exception before, and im a little confused with how to do it, i do want the exception to be in the final block

Comment: Hint: I would worry more about your extensive use of absolutely meaningless index names such as i1, j1, ... and so on. *i* is ok to use for a simple for loop, but what you are doing here is **mind blowing**. There is probably a **huge semantic** difference between the thing that "i1" represents, versus what "i2" means. But syntactically, they are very close together; that makes it 10 times harder to read your code than necessary. Seriously, if you want to improve your code, improve the names of these variables. Same for your method names, use isLegalNeighbor() for methods returning bool.

Comment: What I mean is: probably i1 means "x axis" index; and i2 (or j...) means "y axis". So at least call them x or y instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment and sorry for the hard code, we are not allowed to change the i1\i2\j1\j2 it needs to stay like this since an automatic program checks our code.     i1 and j1 are the  place we start at, and i2,j2 is the place i need to get to. i know my code is a little confusing and i didn't add it all since its kinda long. but is it possible to just show me how to add an exception? or its not possible without me showing all the code? (as in replace the return 0 with an exception that will check the next code block(down), and if that does not work the next one(right)

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible, but it's probably not a good idea.  Exceptions should be truly *exceptional*, not something that is likely to happen.

Not only that, but they are expensive in terms of performance.  You should not be using exceptions to [control flow logic](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl).

Why isn't a true/false return from a method named `isLegalNeighbor` not sufficient?

You really have two methods here: One to calculate distance and another to determine a legal neighbor.  Split them up.  A method should do one thing well, and its name should make clear what that is.

One more bit: I find your code very hard to read.  I would start thinking more about style and how to write more readable code if I were you.

Comment: this is for a school work, and i just need the code to work. the problem with return 0 is once i do that. the code gets stuck and doesn't continue as i wanted. what it is, is a double array that needs to get from point A to B , so the problem of my code. here is a picture to explain
https://s29.postimg.org/l8rqe8ufb/Untitled.jpg

Comment: You have a bigger problem than throwing an exception.  "Just need the code to work" - I thought school work was for learning how to do things properly.  My comments will still help you if you think about them.

Comment: but my code is split up, is legal neighbor checks if i1,j1 and i2,j2 are neighbor's and if so it means i finshed drawing the path. and then i have 4 "if" 
---
locationNeighbor(map,i1-1,j1,i1,j1)==1 this checks if the neighbor is above 
the next if is to check if the neighbor is under (if its equal 2) and 3 is for checking right side and 4 is for left once i do that i know where is the neighbor location ----. now i have a map thats full of -1 and then i start marking the path, to make sure i dont go into endless recursion and i mark the area i have been in with"counter" which counts step

Comment: No, it's not split up.  The method is named "distance", but you're checking for nearest neighbors.  Confusing at best; wrong at worst.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the exception, it's probably not what you want here. First explain what your are trying to achieve. This is completely unobvious from your code.

It's strange that the first if-statement sets a value in map2 but does not return. This means the value might be overwritten by the code below. Is that intended?

I also think there's an error in the line:

```
if(legalNeighbor(map,i1,j1,i1,j2)==false&&i1!=i2&&j1!=j2){
```

The 4th argument i1 should be i2, right?

To make your code more readable you should introduce instance fields and methods with meaningful names. If your tutor is forcing you to use static methods and meaningless names like i1 etc you should fire him/her. :-D

Here's an idea of what I mean:

```
// I chose weird names because I really don't know what's in these arrays
// You should make it clear from the name what it represents
private int[][] fooBar;
private int[][] bazBop;

public int distance(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY, int counter) {
    if (legalNeighbor(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == true) { // if its 1 step before the end
        bazBop[toX][toY] = counter; // put the last number
    }
    int newX = fromX - 1;
    int newY = fromY;
    if (locationNeighbor(newX, newY, fromX, fromY) == 1 && bazBop[newX][newY] == -1) { //up
        bazBop[newX][newY] = counter;
        return distance(newX, newY, toX, toY, counter + 1);
    }
    // ...
}
```